# tkinter frames not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am messing around with the tkinter module for the first time and not quite sure why my widgets aren't being displayed in the correct frame?

"text" and "entry" widgets should be displayed at the top of the top half of the window and "button" and "output" widgets at the top of the bottom half of the window?

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

main_window = Tk()
main_window.title("X SQUARED CALCULATOR")
main_window.geometry("300x300")
mw_frame1 = Frame(main_window).pack()
mw_frame2 = Frame(main_window).pack()

text_widget1 = Label(mw_frame1, text="Please enter a value:").pack(side=TOP)
entry_widget1 = Entry(mw_frame1, text="Please enter a value.").pack(side=TOP)
button_widget1 = Button(mw_frame2, text='Press to calculate!').pack(side=TOP)
output_widget1 = Label(mw_frame2, text="THIS IS WHERE THE NUMBER WILL APPEAR").pack(side=TOP)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a look at 'grid' instead of 'pack', which makes tabular layouts much easier.

Comment: Hi there. Good timing that you posted this - I'm actually messing around with Grid right now but having trouble specifying how many rows and columns I want in the Grid, as I think the default is 2x2?

Comment: @schlenk: switching to grid won't solve the root problem of this question.

Comment: @LuanSwanepoel: there is no default number of rows or columns. You get as many rows and columns as you create.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this:

```
mw_frame1 = Frame(main_window).pack()
```

This sets `mw_frame1` to `None`, because `pack()` returns `None`. Therefore, when you try to make other widgets children of this widget, they actually become children of the root window. Because they are children of the root window, they are being packed in a place you don't expect.

Move your calls to `pack()` to separate statements:

```
mw_frame1 = Frame(...)
mw_frame2 = Frame(...)
...
mw_frame1.pack(...)
mw_frame2.pack(...)
```

Comment: So instead of .pack() at the end should I say my_frame1.pack() on a separate line?

Comment: @LuanSwanepoel: yes. It solves this problem, and is also considered a best practice. I've found that if you put all of your calls to `pack` and `grid` together for each parent, your code becomes much easier to maintain.

Comment: If I do my_frame1.pack() below mw_frame1 = Frame(main_window), I get an error saying not defined.. sigh...

Comment: Oops sorry, made a typo saying my instead of mw

Answer (score 0):

```
text_widget1 = Label(mw_frame1, text="Please enter a value:").pack(side=TOP)
```

Instead write pack separately like this :

```
text_widget1 = Label(mw_frame1, text="Please enter a value:")
text_widget1.pack(side=TOP)
```

It will work.